# UncaughtUncaught syntax error unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, algolia

I'm currently using the Algolia JS API but for some reason I keep randomly getting the following error in console:

```
UncaughtUncaught syntax error unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
```

My current code looks like this:

```
    var params  = {
        hitsPerPage: 10,
        page: 0,
        facets: '*'
    }   
    index.search('some search term', params, function load_search_products_callback(err, content) {
        console.log(content);
    });
```

The problem is that the error occurs before the `console.log(content)` part of the code is run, so I'm unable to actually what the problem is or where it's happening.

Comment: something is **u**ndefined and `JSON.parse` is being run on it ... what is `search_query_term` - can't see where you initialise that - so it could be **u**ndefined

Comment: Sorry, I didn't define it properly in the question, it's just some simple string.

Comment: what type of parameters does `index.search` expect - is that your function, or something from a library?

Comment: That error is normally seen when the value given to `JSON.parse` is actually `undefined`.

Comment: It's from the Algolia API `https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/javascript`

Comment: Which browser? because in the console you can get a stack trace for errors

Comment: I'm running this on Safari but the error was caused on another browser. In Safari I get `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "undefined"`

Comment: add `if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }` to `load_search_products_callback` function for debugging content.

Answer (score 2):

From looking at your code I can predict it is a JS code.

`UncaughtUncaught syntax error unexpected token u in JSON at position 0` occur when you pass undefined to JSON.parse as an argument.

`var a = undefined; 
JSON.parse( a );`

This can be the issue in your code. You need to figure out where this is happening in your code.

I hope that'll help

Comment: `From looking at your code I can predict it is a JS code` - the [javascript] tag was my first clue that the code is javascript